# How to solve $x^{T}Ax = 0$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, quadratic-forms, real-algebraic-geometry, quadrics

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, how do I solve $x^{T}Ax = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Obviously, a zero vector is always a solution and if $A$ is positive or negative definite there is no other solution. However, I'm interested in the cases, where $A$ is neither. Just from plotting a few examples, I believe the solution in the two dimensional case should usually describe one or two lines, but an analytical solution eludes me.

The question [Solving quadratic equations of the form $x'(A-B)x = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269223) seems to be closely related, but it only asks, if there is a solution, not how it looks like and is asking for the complex case. And, truth be told, I don't quite understand the answer anyway.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric and diagonalizable, $x^TP^T\Lambda Px=0$ is equivalent to $y^T\Lambda y=0$, an $n-1$ times indeterminate equation.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution is general, but solutions of $Ax=0$ will satisfy $x^TAx$. If $Z$ is the null space of $A$, then $x=Zy$, where $y$ is any vector of compatible dimensions.

Comment: @CharlieS Yes this is correct. It's the same principle used for annihilators in symmetric bilinear forms.

Comment: @CharlieS: Thanks, but that is just a subset of the solutionos correct? And only works anyway if A has a null space in the first place

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks, but I can't assume that A is symmetric (in fact, it will usually not be symmetric)

Comment: Focus on $n=2$. For example, suppose that $A = \mbox{diag} (1,-1)$. Then, the solution set is defined by $x_1 \pm x_2 = 0$, a pair of lines..

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: On second thought: It may make sense to remove the requirement that A is symmetric. It might be useful for other users like me to see that answers also work for non-diagonizable matrices.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Sorry for dismissing your suggestion at first

Comment: The non-symmetric portion of $A$ has no bearing on the value of $x^TAx$. So it doesn't matter if $A$ is symmetric or not!

Comment: @CharlieS: Yes, I know that now, but others trying to solve the same problem might not (just as me when I rwote the question), so I think that insight should be part of the answer and not a reason to change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Proof that $x^T A x = x^T A_+ x$ for all $x$, where $A_+ = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is the symmetric part of $A$. Then you can apply the spectral theorem.

Comment: @Hyperplane: Thanks. Just as you guessed, I was not aware  (or rather hadn't thought about) that I can assume symetry until Rodrigo told me so in the comments.

Comment: That aside, what is the practice here: Shouldn't an answer contain more than "just" an (admittedly crucial) hint? Believe me or not, this isn't some homework assignment ;). Otherwise I'd be fine with accepting it